# Adding custom fields on to frontend forms

Tags: database, forms, setup-script

I am trying to learn how to add fields onto a form and store them in the database. I am using the registration form for this exercise.

`So far I have:`

- displayed an additional field
- located relevant table in the db that stores the label (eav_attribute), names (customer_entity_varchar) and email (customer_entity)
- set is_required to 1
- displayed label next to field

My problem is that when I input data that field is not saved to the database, also I can leave it blank and the form will still be accepted. I assume this is because I added the data directly to my database (therefore bypassing other functions Magento needs to run).

I have looked around for an answer and found [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3924/how-to-add-one-custom-field-into-register-page-and-get-it-working), which seems to confirm my thought about needing to use a setup script for this task and I also came across [this](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-adding-custom-field-to-customer-address). Between the two of them I was pretty confident I could overcome this issue without any further help but I can't work out:

`from link 1`

- how `customer_account_edit` and `customer_account_create` are identified as being needed?

`from link 2`

- what do the first and second parameters do in `$this->addAttribute()` in the setup script, I can see the third parameter is the values for each column?
- how is the first parameter of setData() decided?

`*snippet from link 2*`

```
<address_setup>
    <setup>
        <module>Excellence_Address</module>
        <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class> <!-- This is the important thing-->
    </setup>
    <connection>
        <use>core_setup</use>
    </connection>
</address_setup>
```

`Setup`

```
$installer = $this;

$installer->startSetup();

$this->addAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id', array(
    'type' => 'varchar',
    'input' => 'text',
    'label' => 'Govt ID No#',
    'global' => 1,
    'visible' => 1,
    'required' => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1
));
Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'govt_id')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('customer_register_address','customer_address_edit','adminhtml_customer_address'))
    ->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to add a field to the registration page and have it saved to the database. thanks to the help of [this tutorial](http://nickwan.wordpress.com/2011/06/01/magento-adding-custom-attribute-to-your-customers/). I have added my code which has done the job.

Sorry there is no explanation to the code or an answer to what is `customer_account_edit` and `customer_account_create` and how is setData() parameter decided. But I thought this code may be helpful for anyone else adding new fields. Hopefully someone with more knowledge will expand on that part

`config.xml`

```
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
            <username>
                <create>1</create>
                <update>1</update>
                <name>1</name>
            </username>
        </customer_account>
    </fieldsets>

    <resources>
        <customforms_reginfo_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Customforms_Reginfo</module>
                <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </customforms_reginfo_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
```

`setup-0.1.0.php`

```
 $installer = $this;

 $installer->startSetup();

 $this->addAttribute('customer', 'username', array(
'type' => 'varchar',
'input' => 'text',
'label' => 'Username',
'global' => 1,
'visible' => 1,
'required' => 1,
'user_defined' => 1,
'visible_on_front' => 1
 ));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
->getAttribute('customer', 'username')
->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit','customer_account_create'))
->save();
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: feel free to mark it as accepted if it is a complete answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is another module by Excellence that you can take a look at over here:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-advanced-shipping-method-development

This basically implements *ONE* new field to checkout which is stored in the DB and has custom JavaScript to make it compulsory.

You can use this website

http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php

to get the source code downloadable as a package.

Let me know if there's something you're unclear about.